# How to refer to a randomised choice

Tags: python, random

How do I refer to a randomised choice? I want the program to print and speak the same choice it made from the list. Code so far:

speaklist = ["wassup", "hello", "how do I help?"]
speak(random.choice(speaklist))

I want to add a:

print(same thing it had chosen from the list)

Comment: `random.choice(speaklist)` just this

Answer (score 1):

You use random correctly, you just need to assign it to variable first:

```
speaklist = ["wassup", "hello", "how do I help?"] 
word = random.choice(speaklist)
speak(word)
print(word)
```

As a curiosity, you can use [seed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed) too:

```
import random

speaklist = ["wassup", "hello", "how do I help?"]
random.seed(0)
speak(random.choice(speaklist))
random.seed(0)
print(random.choice(speaklist))
```

Comment: Note that with `seed`, it stops being random at all.